# HTML how to tell which elements are visible?

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen several solutions which determine when an element is visible in the viewport whilst scrolling the page, but I haven't seen any which do this for elements that are contained in a scrolling container `div` as in the example here.

How would I detect the items as they scroll into view via the scrolling div? And by contrast how would I detect them if they fell out of view. In all cases the overflow elements are not hidden at the outset.

HTML

```
    <div id="mainContainer" class="main">
        <div id="scrollContainer"class="scroller">
            <div id="picturesContainer"class="holder">
                <div id="pictureContainer1" class="picture position1">
                pictureContainer1</div>

                <div id="pictureContainer2" class="picture position2">
                pictureContainer2</div>
                <div id="pictureContainer3" class="picture position3">
                pictureContainer3</div>
                <div id="pictureContainer4" class="picture position4">
                pictureContainer4</div>
                <div id="pictureContainer5" class="picture position5">
                pictureContainer5</div>
                <div id="pictureContainer6" class="picture position6">
                pictureContainer6</div>
                <div id="pictureContainer7" class="picture position7">
                pictureContainer7</div>
                <div id="pictureContainer8" class="picture position8">
                pictureContainer8</div>
                <div id="pictureContainer9" class="picture position9">
                pictureContainer9</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .main{
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        height: 200px;
        width:200px;
        background-color: grey;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .scroller{
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        height: 250px;
        width:250px;
        background-color: lightblue;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow: scroll;
    }

    .picture{
        position:absolute;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: lightyellow;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .position1{
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
    }

    .position2{
        top:0px;
        left:200px;
    }

    .position3{
        top:0px;
        left:400px;
    }

    .position4{
        top:200px;
        left:0px;
    }

    .position5{
        top:200px;
        left:200px;
    }

    .position6{
        top:200px;
        left:400px;
    }

    .position7{
        top:400px;
        left:0px;
    }

    .position8{
        top:400px;
        left:200px;
    }

    .position9{
        top:400px;
        left:400px;
    }

    .holder{
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        width:600px;
        height:600px;
        background-color:lightgreen;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include jQuery library on page first.

```
function getObjDims(obj){
    if (!obj) return false;
    var off = $(obj).offset();
    var t = {
        top:off.top,
        left:off.left,
        width:$(obj).width(),
        height:$(obj).height()
    };
    return {x1:t.left, y1:t.top, x2:t.left+t.width,y2:t.top+t.height}
};
function testInside(pic,box){
    var d=getObjDims(pic);
    return (box.x1<=d.x1 && box.y1<=d.y1 && box.x2>=d.x2 && box.y2>=d.y2)?1:-1;
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inside={};
    var port=$('#scrollContainer');
    var box=getObjDims(port);
    $(window).resize(function(){
        box=getObjDims(port);
    });
    $(port).scroll(function(){      
        var str=[];
        $('.picture').each(function(i){
            var oldState = inside[this.id]!=undefined?inside[this.id]:0;            
            var newState = testInside(this,box);
            inside[this.id]=newState;
            if (oldState!=newState)
                switch (newState){
                    case 1:str.push(this.id);break;// go IN
                    case -1: break;// go OUT
                }
        });
        $('#picStatus').text(str.join(', '));
    });
});
```

Add in HTML for results output:

```
<div style='margin-top:280px;'>Pictures in window (numbers):</div>
<div id='picStatus'></div>
```

It is code based on object's coords, witch are recalculated on scroll event. There are some things to know. IE and, seems to be, Opera takes into consideration width and height of scrollbars themselves, that demands curtain code tuning. I just have suggested solution direction and did not spent much time for debugging this.

And yet, maybe will be useful following (from jquery api about offset):

> Note: jQuery does not support getting
>   the offset coordinates of hidden
>   elements or accounting for borders,
>   margins, or padding set on the body
>   element.

Comment: This seems to work once an object is fully visible. This is plently to go on for me - thanks Igor. I've put the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PSjBN/54/) if anyone wants to see it working. I will work further on this an post updates to it also.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html discusses the issues around viewports, determining their dimensions, and calculating element bounds relative to a viewport's coordinate frame.  Part 2 of that blog post then goes into the implicit viewports in mobile browsers.  He doesn't give code that answers your question exactly, but it's definitely relevant and worth a read.

Comment: Hi this is very interesting, but again it mainly refers to the viewport and not the enclosing element.

Comment: @T9b, isn't it the case that computing visibility (assuming no occlusion by floating elements) is a matter of checking recursively whether an element is within the visible portion of each ancestor that has a computed overflow of other than "show" or a computed "clip" region, and that no ancestor has a computed display of "none" or a computed visibility of other than "visible"?  You still run into problems with ancestors' whose background is the same as their descendants' foreground, but unless you're trying to solve a hard problem like trusted path, you can probably ignore that.

Comment: yes you are right. It is a matter of checking recursively if an element is visible in relation to many things including current scroll position and size of bounding elements. I know this is tough and I'm ignoring the fact that there may be other elements in the page, but really was asking if anyone had a (*cough) ready made solution. Otherwise I'm rolling my own as they say...

Comment: @T9b, sorry.  Can't help you with a ready made solution.  If I had to roll my own, I would start with http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html and modify it to not just walk the offset parent chain, but to walk them all and use the computed x y to compute overlap with viewports (assuming you don't care if only margins and borders are visible) based on the computed style checks I outlined above.  You should be aware though that according to CSS 2, position:fixed negates clipping and overflow:hidden, but in CSS 3 it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your help and input, if I don't receive any other pointers in a couple of days, I'll award you this answer. Thanks again.