# How do I use jQuery to determine when a div is out of view to the right?

Tags: jquery, css, view, visibility, visible

I have a div that displays near a control when it's focused on.  Initially, the div was on the left of the control, and life was easy.  A simple `if left < 0 { left = 0; }` would keep the div on the screen.  Now the div needs to be on the right, and I can't figure out a similar bit of code.  Also, the code needs to determine not only if it's off-screen to the right, but also if it's past the visibility of a (possible) scrollable containing div.  How can I accomplish this?  Assume the scrollable div, if applicable, can be found with `$('.PanelScroll')` and we can call the div needing placement `elem`.

Comment: I asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191789/html-how-to-tell-which-elements-are-visible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of the simple solution I was looking for:

```
var ctrl = $('#<your control id>');         // This is the control that the div is display to the right of.
var elem = $('#<your element id>');         // This is the div that may be out of view.
var panel = $('#<your scrollable div id>');
var left = elem.position().left;
var right = left + elem.outerWidth();

if ((panel.length && (right > panel.innerWidth())) || (right > ($(window).width() + $(window).scrollLeft()))) {
    left = left - ctrl.outerWidth() - elem.outerWidth();
}

if (panel.length) {
    left += panel.scrollLeft();
}

elem.css('left', left);
```