# Disabling a checkbox until an iframe has scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I suspect this is probably not possible due to browser security, however I have a form at the end of which is an iframe displaying our terms and conditions page. Below is a checkbox for agreeing to these terms and conditions.

Other sites I have seen require you to scroll down in the terms and conditions before the checkbox is active but i suspect this is done with a textarea or scrollable div rather than an iframe.

As such is anyone aware of how you can spot when an iframe has scrolled in javascript or jQuery so I can enable the checkbox once it has been scrolled.

Comment: Haven't touched JS much in a long time, but I recall when I was 14 and reading on it from w3schools (I know ...) they had a working example of actions in one window using JS to affect another window. I assume this would work with inline frames too.

Comment: Here is the example I saw a while ago. Looks like it might only apply to windows. http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_opener Not really an answer since if it was (hypothetically) applicable to frames, you would still have to adapt it a lot to do what you want. Hope it at least helps a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code in your embedded document should do it.

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(document).height() <= $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())
                $("#chk", window.parent.document).removeAttr("disabled");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a check box automatically become active after scrolling, and actually cannot see the purpose of it. What difference does it make if the checkbox is active or not when it's hidden?

I would also add that I may have misunderstood your question. Do you want the checkbox to become *selected* after scroll? Again this would be pretty dangerous because you could find that your users end up agreeing to your terms by default because of the code that you are about to write.

Having said all that what you are asking may be answered in the question I asked a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191789/html-how-to-tell-which-elements-are-visible)

Comment: He (his boss?) probably wants it unchecked and greyed out until they scroll to the bottom. Then it becomes checkable.

Comment: it is not a case of making the checkbox visible or not, it is making it disabled by default on page load (which I can do n problem) and then only enabling it (allowing it to be checked) once the user has scroll down in the terms and conditions iframe, thus showing they have at least pretended to read it.

Comment: It's common practice to require a user to scroll to the bottom of a Terms of Service box before checking they accept the terms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that (but I'm not sure you can't). Here is an alternate solution for you:

Simply put the `checkbox` **in** your `iframe`. The user will only see it when having scrolled down the `iframe`.

Hint: you can also put everything in a `div` with fixed size and `overflow-y:scroll` in your CSS. Doing this, the `checkbox` will be in your page.

Comment: the checkbox in the iframe could not be validated as part of the form though. I would like to put it in a scrolling div, however as the content is being pulled from a separate page due to the nature of the CMS its not easily do-able.