# How to know which elements are visible in a Bootstrap scrolling panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a simple way to determine which page elements are currently being displayed (inside a scrolling Bootstrap panel)?

Relevant portion of code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/d451cmwh/

This question was answered back in 2011 with a jQuery-heavy solution; I'm hoping there is a more current / simpler solution available now.
[HTML how to tell which elements are visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191789/html-how-to-tell-which-elements-are-visible)

Thanks!
Michael

Code from fiddle:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
            <span class="pull-right">
                <ul class="nav panel-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab
                            1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="test">

                    <table>
                        <tr id="row1">
                            <td>row 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row2">
                            <td>row 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row3">
                            <td>row 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row4">
                            <td>row 4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row5">
                            <td>row 5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row6">
                            <td>row 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row7">
                            <td>row 7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row8">
                            <td>row 8</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row9">
                            <td>row 9</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row10">
                            <td>row 10</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row11">
                            <td>row 11</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row12">
                            <td>row 12</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row13">
                            <td>row 13</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row14">
                            <td>row 14</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row15">
                            <td>row 15</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row16">
                            <td>row 16</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row17">
                            <td>row 17</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row18">
                            <td>row 18</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row19">
                            <td>row 19</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look for [jquery-visible](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) plugin. ;)

Comment: try with jQuery the `$(this).is(":visible")` return a boolean if the element is visible

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL: It will return true for all 19 elements, since `:visible` only checks if the element has a height/width and opacity more than zero and display not none. It doesn't check if the element is in the hidden part of the parent's scroll height.

Comment: Diego and Louys,  Thank you both very much!!  I ended up using a hybrid involving both of your responses.  It's true that :visible falsely reports items hidden underneath other portions of the parent; however, for my purposes it actually was somewhat beneficial.  The code example by @Louys made for the perfect template (which I made simpler with :visible).  Thanks again for such a tremendous help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm hoping there is a more current / simpler solution available now

Unfortunately you need always loop on each row element in order to know if it is visible. The only possibility is to reduce the amount of code focusing only on the elements of interest.

Therefore my proposal ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d451cmwh/1/)) is:

```js
//
// call the function getVisibleRows on scrolling or windows resize
//

$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {getVisibleRows(e);}, 100)
});
$('#test').on('scroll', getVisibleRows);

function getVisibleRows(e) {
    var str = [];
    var docViewTop = $('#test').closest('.panel-body').offset().top;
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $('#test').closest('.panel-body').outerHeight();
    $('table tr').each(function (idx, ele) {
        var elemTop = $(ele).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(ele).outerHeight();
        if ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop)) {
            str.push($(ele).find('td').text());
        }
    });
    $('#picStatus').text(str.join(', '));
};
```

```css
.row {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.panel-tabs {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;
    clear: both;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.panel-tabs > li {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.panel-tabs > li > a {
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    line-height: .85;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.panel-tabs > li > a:hover {
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.panel-primary > .panel-heading {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-color: #000000;
}

.panel-primary {
    border-color: #000000;
}

.panel-tabs > li.active > a,
.panel-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.panel-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .23);
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.tab-pane {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <ul class="nav panel-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="test">

                        <table>
                            <tr id="row1">
                                <td>row 1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row2">
                                <td>row 2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row3">
                                <td>row 3</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row4">
                                <td>row 4</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row5">
                                <td>row 5</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row6">
                                <td>row 6</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row7">
                                <td>row 7</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row8">
                                <td>row 8</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row9">
                                <td>row 9</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row10">
                                <td>row 10</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row11">
                                <td>row 11</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row12">
                                <td>row 12</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row13">
                                <td>row 13</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row14">
                                <td>row 14</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row15">
                                <td>row 15</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row16">
                                <td>row 16</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row17">
                                <td>row 17</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row18">
                                <td>row 18</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="row19">
                                <td>row 19</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="picStatus"></div>
```